# sym2poly selectively working matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, transfer-function

I'm evaluating a series of theoretical (not necessarily functional) circuits in matlab.  I have been trying to get the transfer function of the circuits and during the process I use the sym2poly function.  Sometimes, sym2poly works and returns the transfer function.  Sometimes it does not.
This is what the code looks like:

```
        [n,d] = numden(eval(v_3/V));

        transH = tf(sym2poly(n),sym2poly(d))
```

n and d are symbolic cell arrays.  The error I get is:

```
Error using sym/sym2poly (line 28)
Not a polynomial.

Error in CircuitGA (line 349)
        n = sym2poly(n);
```

This looks similar to several questions posted a long time ago, but all of those were solved by a bug fix in an updated version of the symbolic math toolbox.  Does it mean that what I am giving it is impossible to turn into a polynomial?

Is there a fix?
Any suggestions of a method that will work for all my circuit arrays?

Maybe a try and catch for if it can return a transfer function?

Comment: Could you provide some input data to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I would except that it's 350 lines long.  This link has a downloadable copy of the evaluation function and some example circuits:    http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA6.html#Downloading        A quick note:  all of his circuits work for the transfer function.  I'm trying to build a GA to modify the circuits for me, so they aren't all pretty.

Comment: 'V'    [3]    [1]    [3]  
    'R'    [1]    [1]    [0]     
    'R'    [3]    [0]    [1]     
    'C'    [1]    [0]    [2]   
    'I'    [2]    [0]    [0]                                           This is the one throwing the error.  They are in 4 columns.